# If two cells match’s in a row then need to give one name and next row match’s need to give another name dynamically in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am little bit confusion to write excel vba code. Please help me out.
Here is the my requirement

If two cells match’s in a row  then need to give one name and next row match’s need to give another name dynamically through loop in excel vba

if cell-A = 1 and cell-B = 2 then frist name again if macthes next row second name

[image]

my code is

```
Sub fill_name()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim nm As String
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim f_name() As String

    For i = 1 To 4

        ReDim f_name(2)
        For j = 1 To 2
            f_name(j) = Cells(j, 12).Value

            If Cells(i, 1).Value = "1" And Cells(i, 3).Value = "2" Then
                Cells(i, 2).Value = f_name(j)
            End If

        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Is something not working?

Comment: Why VBA and not a formula?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need VBA for this. You can achieve this via a formula

Put this formula in `B2` and pull it down

```
=IF(AND(A2=1,C2=2),IF(COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,"Hi")=COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,"Hello"),"Hi","Hello"),"")
```

[image]

If you still want to use VBA then use the above formula like this

```
Sub fill_name()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sFormula As String

    sFormula = "=IF(AND(A2=1,C2=2),IF(COUNTIF(" & _
               "$B$1:$B1,""Hi"")=COUNTIF($B$1:$B1,""Hello"")" & _
               ",""Hi"",""Hello""),"""")"

    '~~> Change this as per your requirement
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("B2:B" & lRow)
            .Formula = sFormula
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

And if you do not want to use the formula but want to loop then use it like this

```
Sub fill_name()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyAr(1 To 2) As String

    MyAr(1) = "Hi"
    MyAr(2) = "Hello"
    j = 1

    '~~> Change this as per your requirement
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To lRow
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = 1 And .Range("C" & i).Value = 2 Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = MyAr(j)
                If j = 1 Then j = 2 Else j = 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, thank you for the solution 
 
Siddharth Rout